# How do I stop a Genymotion virtual device?

Tags: android, eclipse, genymotion

This seems like a strange question to ask, so maybe it is a bug, (and I have no problem starting these virtual devices), but then I notice for each new start of an Android project in Eclipse, I have to recreate these Genymotion VDs. So I end up having duplicates in my Device Manager. I go to try to delete them in the VD Manager and it says, "stop the device before deleting it".. which is weird because there is no stop button. And nothing in settings. Anyone know how to stop it? Thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Do it from the VirtualBox manager:

[image: virtualbox-manager]

Comment: Is there some setting to have that happen whenever the X at the top right hand corner is pushed?

Comment: This helped me but I didn't close the emulator cause it was not running, apparently! So I had to remove it from the VM Box and recreate in Genymotion.

Comment: your answer helped me after 5 years :)

Comment: How to automate this process?

Comment: @ÁlvaroAgüero If you were able to turn off sleepingMode on VB that would solve the problem dramatically

Answer (score 3):

Since the virtualbox monitor does not always offer a shutdown option, you could also log in into the android device and type halt.

adb shell

then type halt at the prompt.

Comment: This is safer than going to VirtualBox and "hard" shutting down. You can also use `adb reboot` to reboot the device instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try Looking in task manager and ending the "Adb" processes if they exist

Comment: Thanks, that might have worked, but now it mysteriously is stopping the emulator when I close it. Even though it didn't do that before. >_< This emulator has so many bugs, I might not be able to really use it.

Comment: Thats odd, i have not got the slightest idea

Answer (score 0):

if you are connected to an android vm with the genymotion frontend, try to press the power-down button (right low corner) and keep pressing it until the shutdown menu appears.

It appears that the genymotiond frontend (player.exe) does not close automaticly after shutdown. Just close it when it's displayed image freezes.... (this is not valid if started directly from virtual box, since genymotions device control buttons are not available then)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where the Virtual Device would crash, and I wouldn't be able to start the device from the summary Genymotion Device Manager (which I accessed from Intellij).

I had to start the main device manager, which wouldn't let me delete or access settings, and warned that I needed to quit the virtual device. I just double clicked to start the device again and it seemed to fix whatever was hung up, and I was able to use the virtual device again, or close it if need be.

Answer (score 0):

> @me.yay: It appears that the genymotiond frontend (player.exe) does not close automaticly after shutdown. Just close it when it's displayed image freezes

Realize this is an old thread, but I just had this issue tonight.  Been using Genymotion for a couple years, so don't know why this is happening now.  The emulator works fine, but when I stop the device via long hold on Power button (thanks me.yay), the VM stops (as seen in VirtualBox manager) but Genymotion hangs on "Power Off Shutting down..." After I close the emulator, I then get a popup from Windows saying "application terminated in an unusual way" from Microsoft C runtime.

Genymotion 3.0.2.